# How do I convert this .Net Post function into VBA?

Tags: .net, vba, vb.net

I'm trying to utilize the API for a tool called AceProject in order to create projects through VBA: http://api.aceproject.com/explorer/?fct=createorcopyproject

My code is functional using GetHTTP, but to allow for longer project descriptions I would like to utilize the Post method instead (so that I'm not restricted to the URL character limit). However I'm unfamiliar with how to convert their code example into VBA and there is no documentation on their site for it beyond what I've linked.

Here's my function call:

```
    Dim RawJSON As String: RawJSON = PostHTTP("?fct=createorcopyproject&guid=" & GUID_ & _
    "&projectnumber=" & ProjectNum & "&projectname=" & ProjectName & "&projecttype=" & ProjectType & "&projectdesc=" & ProjectDesc & _
    "&nexttasknumber=" & TaskNum & _
    "&budgethours=0&budgetcost=0&estimatedstartdate=" & StartDate & _
    "&estimatedhours=0&estimatedexpenses=0&projecttemplate=0&defaultestimatedtime=0&defaulttaskstartdate=2&defaulttaskenddate=2&defaulttaskactualdates=2&projecttemplateid=" & TemplateID & _
    "&keeptemplatelink=False&copyprojectassignments=True&copyprojectdocuments=True&copyforumtopics=True&copytasks=True&adjusttaskdates=True&copytaskdocuments=True&copytaskassignments=True&marklevel=1&format=JSON")
```

And my NON-working Post function:

```
Private Function PostHTTP(ByVal PostStr As String) As String
    On Error Resume Next
    With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
        .Open "POST", "http://api.aceproject.com/", False
        .SetRequestHeader "Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
        .Send (PostStr)
        PostHTTP = .ResponseText
    End With
End Function
```

This is the relevant code from their .Net example:

```
       strXML = CallHttp("http://api.aceproject.com/", sb.ToString)

    Private Shared Function CallHttp( ByVal url As String, _ 
                                      ByVal params As String) As String
        Dim loHttp As System.Net.HttpWebRequest
        loHttp = CType(System.Net.WebRequest.Create(url), System.Net.HttpWebRequest)
        loHttp.Method = "POST"
        Dim requestWriter As System.IO.StreamWriter = New System.IO.StreamWriter(loHttp.GetRequestStream())

        If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(params) Then
            requestWriter.Write(params)
        End If
        requestWriter.Close()
        loHttp.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
        loHttp.Headers.Set("Pragma", "no-cache")
        loHttp.AllowAutoRedirect = True
        loHttp.KeepAlive = True
        loHttp.Timeout = 30 * 1000

        Dim loWebResponse As System.Net.HttpWebResponse = CType(loHttp.GetResponse(), System.Net.HttpWebResponse)
        Dim enc As Encoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8
        Dim loResponseStream As System.IO.StreamReader = New System.IO.StreamReader(loWebResponse.GetResponseStream(), enc)
        Dim lcHtml As String = loResponseStream.ReadToEnd()

        loWebResponse.Close()
        loResponseStream.Close()

        Return lcHtml
    End Function
```

Is there any way, using the information above, that I can send my URL string via post instead of get?

Comment: I may have just got it working, came down to having a "?" in my string leftover from using the Get method

Answer (score 0):

This is the final working version (created a test project with a 20k character description), hopefully this'll help someone out.

Function Call:

```
Private Const BASE_URL = "http://api.aceproject.com/"

    Dim RawJSON As String: RawJSON = PostHTTP(BASE_URL, "fct=createorcopyproject&guid=" & GUID_ & _
    "&projectnumber=" & ProjectNum & "&projectname=" & ProjectName & "&projecttype=" & ProjectType & "&projectdesc=" & ProjectDesc & _
    "&nexttasknumber=" & TaskNum & _
    "&budgethours=0&budgetcost=0&estimatedstartdate=" & StartDate & _
    "&estimatedhours=0&estimatedexpenses=0&projecttemplate=0&defaultestimatedtime=0&defaulttaskstartdate=2&defaulttaskenddate=2&defaulttaskactualdates=2&projecttemplateid=" & TemplateID & _
    "&keeptemplatelink=False&copyprojectassignments=True&copyprojectdocuments=True&copyforumtopics=True&copytasks=True&adjusttaskdates=True&copytaskdocuments=True&copytaskassignments=True&marklevel=1&format=JSON")
```

Post Function:

```
Private Function PostHTTP(ByVal URL As String, ByVal PostStr As String) As String
    On Error Resume Next
    With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
        .Open "POST", URL, False
        .SetRequestHeader "Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
        .Send (PostStr)
        PostHTTP = .ResponseText
    End With
End Function
```